# how to log the last search request when autocomplete is in place?

Tags: autocomplete, redux-saga

For example, when a user types `android` .

A client sends multiple requests to the server 
namely
`a`
`an`
`and` and so on.

I'd like to log the `android` search request only in the server.
How can I do that?

I'm thinking of the following strategy, but wonder if there's a better one.

1. do the autocomplete as before
2. send the special `log this search request` if `1 sec` has passed after a user pressed keyboard

If I were to implement the above, how would one use `redux-saga` to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement [debounce](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/docs/recipes/README.md#debouncing) in bunch of `takeLatest` effects. So, if i.e. your component dispatches `INPUT_CHANGED` action, then your saga will look like:

```
import { call, takeLatest, delay } from 'redux-saga/effects'

function* handleLog(action) {
  // debounce by 1 sec
  yield delay(1000); 
  if (action.payload.LOG_THIS_SEARCH_REQUEST) {
     const apiResult = yield api.log(action.payload.value);
     ...  // logic after api call is done
  }
}

function* watchInput() {
  // log latest input change
  yield takeLatest('INPUT_CHANGED', handleLog);
}
```

So, in provided example, if in 1 sec user triggers a new input change (i.e. add one more letter), then saga will handle only latest one.

Comment: Thanks, did you just effectively implement redux-saga's `debounce` effect?